# scroll and focus to active link in navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this sample code.

```
<ul id="navigation"  onLoad="$.scrollTo('.active',800, {easing:'elasout'});">
      <li class="no_border"><a href="Item1.html">Item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="Item2.html">Item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="Item3.html">Item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="Item4.html">Item4</a></li>
      <li><a href="Item5.html">Item5</a></li>
      <li><a href="Item6.html">Item6 </a></li>
      <li><a href="Item7.html">Item7 </a></li>
      <li><a href="Item8.html">Item8 </a></li>
      <li><a href="Item9.html">Item9</a></li>
      <li><a href="Item10.html">Item10</a></li>
      <li><a href="Item11.html">Item11 </a></li>
      <li><a href="Item12.html" class="active">Item12</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have my browser resized at 375px. I want the browser to automatically 'scroll' to the item that is active. is it possible? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have made function to fulfil your need, but you have to use "jQuery" for this :

core function :

```
(function($){
    $.scrollTo = function(target, speed, style){
        if(typeof target === 'string'){
            var pos = $(target).offset().top;
        }else if(typeof target === 'object'){
            var pos = target.offset().top;
        }

        var userSetting = {
            speed: speed,
            style: style
        }

        var setting = $.extend({
            speed: 300,
            style: 'swing'
        }, userSetting);

        if(typeof pos !== 'undefined'){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: pos
            },setting.speed, setting.style);
        }
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Execute funtion like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.scrollTo('.active',800, 'swing');
});
```

Hope, This will help you...

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. it only scrolls to halfway of the whole page. it's horizontal btw.